# Unity C# Camera Axis of Rotation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera

Some people probably think that this question belongs on the Unity Answers forum, but i can't get any help there.

So I have this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject player;

    private Vector3 offset;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void LateUpdate () {
        transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
        transform.rotation = player.transform.rotation;
        transform.Rotate (new Vector3 (45, 00));
    }
}
```

And it works. But whenever the camera turns, the player goes out of focus. Here us in image depicting this (circled area is the player):

[image: Circled area is the player.]

**Edit:**

Screenshot showing the camera position:

[image: Camera Position]

Comment: Select the player in the debug mode. And show us what are the position and rotation of both the player and the camera and what are the desired values for the camera. Also let me know if the values of the camera keep changing with time without the change of the player's values.

Comment: You might want to look into unity's lerp function and check the player's culling